# Create a mock Request object in Loopback 4

Tags: unit-testing, request, mocking, loopback4

I've got a Loopback 4 controller, and I want to unit test it.  How do I mock the request parameter?  Here's the constructor to my controller:

```
  constructor(@inject(RestBindings.Http.REQUEST) private req: Request,
              @service(HttpService) private httpService: HttpService,
              @service(LocalRequestService) private localRequestService: LocalRequestService) {}
```

I tried mocking it with `createStubInstance(Request)`, but that gave me this error:

```
Argument of type 'StubbedInstanceWithSinonAccessor<Request>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.
  Type 'StubbedInstanceWithSinonAccessor<Request>' is missing the following properties from type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>': get, header, accepts, acceptsCharsets, and 68 more.ts(2345)
```

Answer (score 0):

stubExpressContext can be used.

```
const context = stubExpressContext();
const controller = new MyController(context.request);
```

Options can be passed to stubExpressContext.

[More..](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@loopback/testlab/v/0.10.7?activeTab=readme#test-code-expecting-express-request-or-response)